# Why does Envers skip revisions?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

We are at the point of integrating Hibernate Envers into our project. Everything works fine, but we noticed it sometimes skips a revision. In the code below, I expect to have 3 revisions (1, 2 and 3) of the entity:

```
Building building = new Building();
building.setStatus("new");
buildingRepository.save(building);

building.setStatus("building");
buildingRepository.saveAndFlush(building);

building.setStatus("finished");
buildingRepository.saveAndFlush(building);
```

Note: buildingRepository is a JPA repository

When I read all revisions from the DB with

```
auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Building.class, false, true).getResultList();
```

I get revisions 1, 3 and 4. Why is revision 2 being skipped ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems my understanding of Envers at that time was not good. Envers does not keep revisions per entity, but globally. This I did not know. Inbetween the above listed actions, was a creation of another entity that received revision 2.